# Magento 2.2 Update order custom attribute value

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, upgrade

I have tried to update order attribute value which is created custom. attribute are updated but after `$order->save();` I got an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-payment/Observer/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php:24
```

Any idea about this?

Please Check My code for your refrence:

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderData[0]);
$order->setData('ordernum',$orderData[1]);
$order->setData('salesforceid',$orderData[2]);
$order->setData('trackingsummary',$orderData[3]);
$order->setData('shippingstatus',$orderData[4]);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Event

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
<observer instance="vendor\module\Observer\Sales\OrderPlaceAfter" name="vendor_module_observer_sales_orderplaceafter_sales_order_place_after"/>
</event>
```

Comment: sorry i am update order attribute not on specific event. its custom button to update attribute